# After Google Sign in, my app won't move to the next activity

Tags: android, google-signin

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,View.OnClickListener {

    private SignInButton signInButton;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    public static final String TAG="MainActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions=new GoogleSignInOptions
                .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();

        googleApiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this,this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,googleSignInOptions).build();
        signInButton=(SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.mainactivitygooglesigninbutton);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> googleSignInResultOptionalPendingResult = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(googleApiClient);
        if(googleSignInResultOptionalPendingResult.isDone()){
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,ContactsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.mainactivitygooglesigninbutton:
                signIn();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent intent=Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(intent,RC_SIGN_IN);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==RC_SIGN_IN){
            GoogleSignInResult result=Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if(result.isSuccess()){
            GoogleSignInAccount account=result.getSignInAccount();
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,ContactsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }


}
```

On success full sign in my app does not move to Contacts Activity. I have used the internet permission and all the activities are registered in Manifest file.Even in Android Monitor I am not getting any error nor my app crashes.

I am signed in my Google and Google Plus account in my phone. On click of sign in button it shows me the option to choose the account but after that nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Debug your app or add logging to see if and with what parameters your onActivityResult is called.

Comment: its because its in your oncreate method. that only gets called when the app launches and thats it. if should probably go in the on click for signing in. so ur onclick called signIn(), u need to follow through your code and see where it should go. i recommend putting in Log tags

Comment: take a peek here. https://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/